# Is there a postfix mysql virtual_maps append_at_origin workaround so I can pipe to external scripts?

Tags: mysql, postfix, email-server, virtualhost

I am using virtual domains, and I'd like to setup the server to alias to custom scripts.  I manage all accounts using postfix mappings to mysql.

It seems that postfix automatically appends a virtual domain regardless of how the forwarded/aliased result comes back.  So even though i have:

```
"|/bin/command"
```

postfix is reading it as:

```
"|/bin/command"@mydomain.com
```

Is there any work-around, or setting I can fix?

It would seem than `append_at_myorigin=no` would be ideal, but that's unsupported according to the documentation.

Another option, maybe I can skip virtual aliases altogether and use the "/etc/postfix/aliases" table - assuming all emails go to the main domain.  I'll try this, but if anyone has any other ideas how to make it work with virtual domains, please let me know as this would be very useful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way i do it is to alias

in postfix/virtual create an alias to a "local alias" in /etc/aliases

```
postfix/virtual
domain@domain.co.uk        domain_alias@localhost
```

then in /etc/aliases you can pipe the alias to a script

```
/etc/aliases
domain_alias:                 "|/bin/command"
```

This works well for me.

Comment: Just as a side node: This is the only way to do it. Virtual aliases cannot use shell commands directly. In a virtual context Postfix doesn't have a notion of system users.